# Tiny int store limited values in db

Tags: mysql

I've created field named e2s with `tinyint` datatype. When I store the value of `500` it converts it into `127`. Now I changed it to `smallint`. It stored value `500`. Why?
What is the difference between `int`, `tinyint`, `smallint`, `mediumint`, `bigint` to store values.

Comment: The difference is in the amount of bits used to store it. Tinyint uses 8 bit to store the value which maps to a range of -128 to 127 .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a failure to even consult [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

Comment: but the length was 4 of my field

Comment: @Phil you could say rtfm to a majority of qUestions around here

Comment: @user2727841 The number in parenthesis is **not** *length*. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045327/is-there-a-difference-in-using-int1-vs-tinyint1-in-mysql/8045378#8045378

Comment: @no_answer_not_upvoted I fully intend to

Comment: @Phil that's behavior worthy of an ... thanks for opening up.

Comment: Here is a table of the numeric types and their ranges: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52104781/2430549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html. `TINYINT` only stores 1 byte of data, thus allowing the integer range of storage from -128 to 127.

`SMALLINT` in other hand uses 2 bytes of storage, having a much wider range from -32768 to 32767.

Be aware of what you are going to store in `TINYINT` or `SMALLINT` columns. For instance, it's a bad idea to set an `auto_increment` PK column to `SMALLINT` datatype as you could easily overwhelm it's capacity.

Comment: Thanks. Now I've understand

Comment: To be clear: this is meant for signed version, unsigned can store 0-255. (similarly this applies to any other int type that can be marked unsigned)

Answer (score 0):

Please see MySql reference on integer types:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html

It shows you the minimum and maximum values you can store.